# Append a text in a file where the pattern matches

Tags: python, regex, file, append

I have a text file named text.txt

content of text.txt:

```
1. Luv_dev
2. Amit_dev
3. Sandeep_supp
4. Prateek_supp
5. Sumit_dev
6. Shashank_dev
7. Kush_supp
8. Ritesh_dev
9. Shubham_supp
10. Ravi_dev
```

I need to append a text(which i call as description of the profile) after every name.

Example: In the 1st line "1. Luv_dev" I want to append "<- He's a developer" after it, because it contains the keyword "_dev".

Similarly, for 3rd line "3. Sandeep_supp" i want to append "<- He's a support guy" after it, because it contains the keyword "_supp".

So bottom line i want my text file to be something like this:

```
1. Luv_dev <- He's a developer
2. Amit_dev <- He's a developer
3. Sandeep_supp <- He's a support guy
4. Prateek_supp <- He's a support guy
5. Sumit_dev <- He's a developer
6. Shashank_dev <- He's a developer
7. Kush_supp <- He's a support guy
8. Ritesh_dev <- He's a developer
9. Shubham_supp <- He's a support guy
10. Ravi_dev <- He's a developer
```

I have started doing it but i don't think i'm on the right track of achieving my goal.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import re

 file = open("text.txt","a")
 for line in file:
     match_for_dev = re.match(r"\d+\.\s\w+_dev$",line)
     match_for_supp = re.match(r"\d+\.\s\w+_supp$",line)
     if match_for_dev:
          file.write("<- He's a developer")
     if match_for_supp:
          file.write("<- He's a support guy")
```

this code is not giving me anything :(

Comment: the chances are, either your regexp is not matching anything, or you are not closing the file and it is not completely written. Start with closing the file at the end (best using the `with open("text.txt", "a") as file:` context manager.

Comment: @Distributed_Entity as the answer pointed out, you are trying to read and write to the same file at once. This is not possible for text file (and is hard for binary ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your issues is you are attempting to *read* from a file which is opened for *writing*. This is not possible. You need to read from one file, and write to another. The below code uses the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)-statement to open the input file and an output file.

You don't need regular expressions here. You can simply check if the line ends with either `dev` or `supp` and append the text you want accordingly. For that, use the  [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as inp, open("out.txt", "w") as output:
   for line in inp:
       l = line.strip()
       if l.endswith("dev"):
           output.write("{} <- He's a developer\n".format(l))
       if l.endswith("supp"):
           output.write("{} <- He's a support guy\n".format(l))
```

---

Your python version is *six years old*. You should consider updating to at least python 2.7.x but preferrably to python 3.x. The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)-statement is not available in python 2.4. You have to open and close the files manually:

```
inp = open("text.txt", "r")
output = open("out.txt", "w")

for line in inp:
    l = line.strip()
    if l.endswith("dev"):
       output.write("%s <- He's a developer\n" % l)
    if l.endswith("supp"):
       output.write("%s <- He's a support guy\n" % l)

inp.close()
output.close()
```

Outputs to out.txt:

```
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ cat out.txt 
1. Luv_dev <- He's a developer
2. Amit_dev <- He's a developer
3. Sandeep_supp <- He's a support guy
4. Prateek_supp <- He's a support guy
5. Sumit_dev <- He's a developer
6. Shashank_dev <- He's a developer
7. Kush_supp <- He's a support guy
8. Ritesh_dev <- He's a developer
9. Shubham_supp <- He's a support guy
10. Ravi_dev <- He's a developer
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$
```

Comment: I am getting some error on your code if i run it.                                         `File "./Text_manipulation.py", line 3 with open("text.txt", "r") as inp, open("out.txt", "w") as output: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: My version of Python is 2.4.6

Comment: @Disturbed_Entity updated my answer. Please consider udpating your python.

Comment: I'm getting a Blank out.txt :(
nothing's matching in those if conditions, i tried to print something under both the "if" clauses to test whether the controls goes into them or not, but neither of the statements ran, it means it's not matching anything from the file text.txt and am i getting a blank out.txt.
Do my version supports str.endswith()?  your code doesn't give me any errors while i run it.

Comment: Then your lines do not end as you say they do. Your version supports `str.endswith()`.

Comment: I corrected that but now i'm getting this error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Text_manipulation.py", line 9, in ?
    output.write("{} <- He's a developer\n".format(l))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: python 2.4 does not have `str.format`. Updated my answer to use old style string format.

Comment: Thanks at last it worked :D ,I should really change my version of python.
where can i get a good tutorial on the text-file manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

## testing by `line.rsplit()`

There are multiple methods how to test the role, one bing `rsplit`, which takes defined string as delimiter and starts splitting the line from the right side as many times as specified in next parameter.

```
>>> line "name_surname_role".rsplit("_", 1)
["name_surname", "role"]
```

I also changed the logic to find full role name from dictionary.

In case the role is not present, "unknown role" is used as default.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
fname = "text.txt"
outfname = "outtext.txt"
roles = {"dev": "developer", "supp": "support guy"}
with open(fname, "r") as in_f, open(outfname, "w") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = line.strip()
        role = line.rsplit("_", 1)[-1]
        print role
        rolename = roles.get(role, "unknown role")
        out_f.write("{line} <- He's a {rolename}\n".format(**locals()))
```

In case you are found of older versions of Python not having any idea what `string.format` is about, change the line

```
    out_f.write("{line} <- He's a {rolename}\n".format(**locals()))
```

into

```
    out_f.write("%s <- He's a %s\n" % (line, rolename))
```

This will work with recent Python too.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with your code as well `dev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tm.py", line 12, in ?
    out_f.write("{line} <- He's a {rolename}\n".format(**locals()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: @Disturbed_Entity In my Python 2.7.6 it runs well. If you are using Python 2.4.6, then sorry.

Comment: @Disturbed_Entity I added instruction, how to make it running in older pythons too.

Answer (score 0):

I have my code working as well :D

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

input = open("text.txt","r")
output = open("out.txt","w")
for line in input:
    match_for_dev = re.search(r"\d+\.\s\w+_dev$",line)
    match_for_supp = re.search(r"\d+\.\s\w+_supp$",line)
    if match_for_dev:
            output.write("%s <- He's a developer\n" % match_for_dev.group(0))
    if match_for_supp:
            output.write("%s <- He's a support guy\n" % match_for_supp.group(0))

input.close()
output.close()
```

Thank you all for your answers :)